# When crawling the text from the website by using the scrapy ,it will crawl all the content but not crawl the link content ,how to solve the issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

when crawl the data full content is not crawled ,here tag content is not crawled  and also how to crawl tag href at a time.

Html.code

```
<p class="gnt_ar_b_p">
24/7 Tempo has compiled a list of drugs in short supply from information provided by the 
   <p class="gnt_ar_b_p">
   However, drugs are frequently announced to be in short supply. In 
   fact, the FDA has a running list of drug shortages due to anything from increasing demand 
   to regulatory factors as well as supply disruptions.
   </p>
  <a href="https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/drugshortages/default.cfm" data-t- 
   l="|inline|intext|n/a" class="gnt_ar_b_a">
   Food and Drug Administration</a>.
</p>
```

shell

```
response.css('p.gnt_ar_b_p').xpath("text()").extract()
```

output

```
24/7 Tempo has compiled a list of drugs in short supply from information provided by the 
However, drugs are frequently announced to be in short supply. In 
fact, the FDA has a running list of drug shortages due to anything from increasing demand 
to regulatory factors as well as supply disruptions.
```

Comment: `response.css('p.gnt_ar_b_p')` here, I think your just selecting `p.gnt_ar_b_p` elements. Try remove the `p` tag.

Comment: I tried then also not getting the <a> text.